# how to autostart certaim program in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I have two users in windows 10, one is administrator.
Another one doesn't have admin rights.
So it cannot start exe-programm.

How can i make certain program startup with admin rights?

I tried to login as administrator and set the programm autostart, but it doesnt actually run at the startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a task in Windows Task Scheduler.

1) Specify admin account in security options of general tab and mark box "Run with highest privileges"

2) Go to triggers and select "On logon", then specify particular user.

An example you can find here -https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/67503-task-create-run-program-startup-log.html

Answer (score -1):

One of the way to do it is to run the program as a service. There is a lot of advantages to do so, one of it being able to start the program even before the user login.

Under the admin user account, you can use sc.exe to create a service. Details are documented in this Microsoft documentation:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create

Then be sure right-click the service > Properties and set the Logon As in the Logon tab using the admin user.